# Is it possible to make a local Chrome web app with offline sensible-data storage?

Tags: security, web-applications, google-chrome, local, offline

I would like to create a 100% offline web app in Chrome that stores sensible data. Are there any security issues and if yes, which ones?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't easily make offline apps that are based on file:// urls, you can however create apps that are hosted on a server that are made to work entirely offline.

Read about [AppCache](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html), [LocalStorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/), [WebSQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/), [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) and [FileSystem](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/) API's

If you really really don't want to host it, package your code up as a [Packaged App](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/apps.html)